# In MUI X Charts, how to prevent LineChart Y axis label from overlapping with ticks labels?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, charts, mui-x, mui-x-charts

I have been using very basic [LineChart](https://mui.com/x/react-charts/lines/) that renders like this:

[image: LineChart with yAxis label overlap]

As you can see, the `Money` label is overlapping with the ticks. What is the best way of avoiding this?

Source of the `LineChart`:

```js
  const xAxisMax = _.max(turns) ?? defaultXAxisMax
  const yAxisMax = _.max(money) ?? defaultYAxisMax
  return (
    <LineChart
      xAxis={[
        {
          data: turns,
          min: 1,
          max: xAxisMax,
          label: 'Turns',
          scaleType: 'linear',
        },
      ]}
      yAxis={[
        {
          min: 0,
          max: yAxisMax,
          label: 'Money',
          scaleType: 'linear',
          //labelStyle: { ??? },
        },
      ]}
      series={[
        {
          data: money,
        },
      ]}
      width={500}
      height={300}
    />
  )
}
```

Relevant lines from my `npm ls`

```
+-- @emotion/react@11.11.3
+-- @emotion/styled@11.11.0
+-- @fontsource/roboto@5.0.8
+-- @mui/icons-material@5.15.5
+-- @mui/material@5.15.5
+-- @mui/x-charts@6.19.1
+-- @vitejs/plugin-react@4.2.1
+-- lodash@4.17.21
+-- react-dom@18.2.0
+-- react@18.2.0
+-- typescript@5.3.3
+-- vite@5.0.12
```

In the docs, I found some mentions of example customizations here:

https://mui.com/x/react-charts/axis/#text-customization

which says:

```js
<ScatterChart
  {/** ... */}
  bottomAxis={{
    labelStyle: {
      fontSize: 14,
      transform: `translateY(${
            // Hack that should be added in the lib latter.
            5 * Math.abs(Math.sin((Math.PI * props.angle) / 180))
          }px)`
    },
    tickLabelStyle: {
      angle: 45,
      textAnchor: 'start',
      fontSize: 12,
    },
  }}
```

This plus few other relevant articles make me believe I could somehow apply the `labelStyle` of `yAxis`. However, whatever I try, `padding`, `margin`, and so on, it always appears to be overridden/ignored by the rendered page, as inspected by Chrome DevTools.

However, `transform` appears to be actually rendered, e.g.:

`labelStyle: { transform: 'rotate(-90deg)' },`

but I do not know what is the correct value of `transform` to just shift the label a little bit more to the side.

Note I do not have any css customizations anywhere impacting any kind of layout. No custom layout in `<ThemeProvider>` and no other shenanigans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the CSS solution for it, we can just add a class to the chart, to prevent the CSS affecting other charts!

[MuiChartsYAxis-directionY docs](https://mui.com/x/api/charts/charts-y-axis/#ChartsYAxis-css-directionY)

```
.custom-y-padding-bottom .MuiChartsAxis-directionY .MuiChartsAxis-label {
  transform: translateX(-10px) !important;
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-gbeyob?description=React%20%20%20TypeScript%20starter%20project&file=src%2FApp.tsx,src%2Fstyle.css,package.json&title=React%20Starter)

Comment: Thanks, it works! Curiously, adding to `LineChart`'s `yAxis` the following: `labelStyle: { transform: 'translateX(-10px) !important' }` appears to have no effect.

Comment: Just to add: the approach in this answer is described in MUI docs as "Global CSS" here: https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#global-css

Comment: @KonradJamrozik Actually, when I did that, the label got repositioned to somewhere outside the screen, so setting that property will not give a proper solution so I am suggesting this approach!

Comment: Totally, already upvoted :) I just wanted to wait few days to give people time to answer and accept the best one :)

Answer (score 2):

To give more explanation about why using the `labelStyle` does not do anything:

The texts are structures as follow:

```
<g class="MuiChartsAxis-label">
  <text x=".." y=".." transform="...">
    <tspan>...</tspan>
  </text>
</g>
```

The `labelStyle` will add some style to the `<text/>` but the transform will never win face to the attributes.

The group with class `MuiChartsAxis-label` is here to let you manipulate the text position. By the way you might not need to us `!important`. See for example the demo of https://mui.com/x/react-charts/axis/#composition